# Regex with double brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to parse some data which is the following form called `data`:

```
data = '(def-instance Adelphi
   (expenses thous$:7-10)
   (academic-emphasis biology))
(def-instance Arizona-State
   (expenses thous$:4-7)
   (academic-emphasis fine-arts))'
```

I want to split the data into a list such that first paragraph is in first entry and second paragraph in the second entry i.e.:

```
['(def-instance Adelphi
   (expenses thous$:7-10)
   (academic-emphasis business-administration)
   (academic-emphasis biology))', 
'(def-instance Arizona-State
   (expenses thous$:4-7)
   (academic-emphasis fine-arts)']
```

I tried using the command `re.split(r'\(*(\([^()]*\)*)*\)',data)` but I am off slightly and I cannot see why. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not split on the double newline?

Comment: @Brian, or two or more consecutive newlines.

Comment: sorry there is no newline. I have made changes  to the question asked above

Comment: @AnmolAggarwal, Cary's suggestion was to split by _consecutive_ newlines, not just newlines. That should work for you.

Comment: A non-regex way would be to keep a count of the number of open brackets - add one for `(` and subtract one for `)`, then split when the count is 0

Comment: Hi @Ollie, thank you for comments. I am new to python so can you please show me how can this be achieved. thanks

Comment: @AnmolAggarwal is this stored in a file? I want to read this in correctly and I get an EOF error when I read this the same way in python.

Comment: This input data is invalid in Python. This looks like a string, but line breaks like this are not allowed. Can you represent this as valid Python data?

Comment: Thing is that infact I have 405 such groups of brackets in a string. And I want to split them in 405 ways. is there a way to share the file in stackoverflow?

Comment: Give a smaller, summarized set. For instance, say you have a list of integers 0-10. You could represent as: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, or `[0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 10]`

Comment: hope this makes more sense @SamMorgan

Comment: What format is that? It looks like a Lisp.

Comment: You can use a service like pastebin to share large amounts of text. If this is lisp, I was able to find a python lisp parser that might help https://gist.github.com/roberthoenig/30f08b64b6ba6186a2cdee19502040b4

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating over your data, searching for `))` and creating the result list based on the index and values you find.

```
data = data.split('\n')

result = list()
prev = 0

for idx, value in enumerate(data):
    if '))' in value:
        result.append('\n'.join(data[prev:idx + 1]))
        prev = idx + 1
```

This outputs:

```
print(result)
#['(def-instance Adelphi\n   (state newyork)\n   (control private)\n   (no-of-students thous:5-10)\n   (male:female ratio:30:70)\n   (student:faculty ratio:15:1)\n   (sat verbal 500)\n   (sat math 475)\n   (expenses thous$:7-10)\n   (percent-financial-aid 60)\n   (no-applicants thous:4-7)\n   (percent-admittance 70)\n   (percent-enrolled 40)\n   (academics scale:1-5 2)\n   (social scale:1-5 2)\n   (quality-of-life scale:1-5 2)\n   (academic-emphasis business-administration)\n   (academic-emphasis biology))', '(def-instance Arizona-State\n   (state arizona)\n   (control state)\n   (no-of-students thous:20+)\n   (male:female ratio:50:50)\n   (student:faculty ratio:20:1)\n   (sat verbal 450)\n   (sat math 500)\n   (expenses thous$:4-7)\n   (percent-financial-aid 50)\n   (no-applicants thous:17+)\n   (percent-admittance 80)\n   (percent-enrolled 60)\n   (academics scale:1-5 3)\n   (social scale:1-5 4)\n   (quality-of-life scale:1-5 5)\n   (academic-emphasis business-education)\n   (academic-emphasis engineering)\n   (academic-emphasis accounting)\n   (academic-emphasis fine-arts))']
```

And on your updated data set:

```
result
#['(def-instance Adelphi\n   (expenses thous$:7-10)\n   (academic-emphasis biology))', '(def-instance Arizona-State\n   (expenses thous$:4-7)\n   (academic-emphasis fine-arts))']
```

Answer (score 0):

The one thing the split positions have in common is that they end the previous 'set' with a `)`, have a newline, and then the next 'set' starts with `((`. That suggests the following, using a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```py
import re

data = '''(def-instance Adelphi
   (expenses thous$:7-10)
   (academic-emphasis biology))
(def-instance Arizona-State
   (expenses thous$:4-7)
   (academic-emphasis fine-arts))'''

l = list(re.split(r'(?<=\)\))\s+(?=\()', data))
for item in l:
    print (item)
    print ()
```

with the output (printed in separate lines for clarity):

```
(def-instance Adelphi
   (expenses thous$:7-10)
   (academic-emphasis biology))

(def-instance Arizona-State
   (expenses thous$:4-7)
   (academic-emphasis fine-arts))
```